# Why Plot does not work for a my function?

Tags: plotting

I wanted to make a simple plot as follows:

```
T=((2 + 1.5 y)^2 (0.8 + 4.5y^2) + 4.5 y^2 (0.8 + 12 y + 9. y^2)x + 40.5 y^4 
x^2)/(4 ((2 + 1.5 y)^2 +4.5 y^2 x));

yy[z_]:= FindRoot[4 (y + (T /. x -> z)) y == 1, {y, 0}];

Plot[yy[z],{z,0,5}]
```

In words, there is a functional relation $f(x,y)=1$, and I defined function $yy:R_+ \rightarrow R_+$ as the mapping from value of $x$ to an implicitly determined $y$. This function works well: I tried to plug in any number into 
    yy[z]
and a reasonable value will be returned. However, the Plot does not give any result. Is this a bug, or is there any problem in my code?

Comment: You need `Plot[y /. yy[z], {z, 0, 5}]`. Did you try to debug your code and see what yy[3] gives you?

Answer (score 4):

As @Vitaly suggested, if you use

```
yy[z_] := FindRoot[4 (y + (T /. x -> z)) y == 1, {y, 0}];
```

you find

```
In[58]:= yy[3]

Out[58]= {y -> 0.294456}
```

and that cannot be plotted, unless you modify `yy[z_]` as:

```
yy[z_] := FindRoot[4 (y + (T /. x -> z)) y == 1, {y, 0}][[1, 2]];
```

which gives you:

```
In[63]:= yy[3]

Out[63]= 0.294456
```

and that can be plotted. Using

```
Plot[y /. yy[x], {x, 0, 5}]
```

is also fine, of course.

Comment: Oh I got it. Thanks dude!

Answer (score 3):

[`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) can provide the complete solution

```
T = ((2 + 1.5 y)^2 (0.8 + 4.5 y^2) + 
      4.5 y^2 (0.8 + 12 y + 9. y^2) x + 
      40.5 y^4 x^2)/(4 ((2 + 1.5 y)^2 + 4.5 y^2 x)) // Rationalize // 
  FullSimplify

(*  (128 + 3*y*(64 + 3*y*(88 + 16*x + 
                120*(1 + 2*x)*y + 
                45*(y + 2*x*y)^2)))/
   (40*(16 + 3*y*(8 + (3 + 6*x)*y)))  *)

yy2[x_] = y /. Solve[{4 (y + T) y == 1, 0 <= x <= 5}, y, Reals];

Plot[Evaluate@yy2[x], {x, 0, 5},
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue},
 PlotLegends -> Automatic,
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]